# Are there separate bootstrap files for its different components?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I want to give up all of `twitter bootstrap's` goods and use only the `css` for inputs:  **design**, **behavior** and **validators**.
Is there any separate `css` file for that and for other bootstrap components? 
Taking only the code I need from base bootstrap `css` file by hand is annoying.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer so I would be able to set it as an answer. Thanks a bunch @JamesAllardice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the customize option, Or what I tend to use is: https://github.com/mdo/preboot this was the starting point for bootstrap and offers alot of mixins to use that achieve what I want without all the framework.